# The code needs to be updated to match PHP7

Tags: php, html

The website is shown blank because the code needs to be updated to PHP7.

To give context, I am not a developer but I am supporting website maintenance in our organization.

Recently the server of our website was upgraded to PHP7 and our website running on wordpress stopped working. The recommendation that we received was that a line of code in our website needs to updated to PHP7. Can some of you please look into the code and suggest what needs to be changed.

```
{    
     //OLD CODE: $this->output .= $this->$rule['key'][$rule]."\n";
     $this->output .= $this->$rule['key']($rule)."\n";
}
```

The website is showing blank now, apparently, replacing with the OLD CODE puts everything in the site out of place. We need it to show content like it used to.

Comment: is `$this->rule['key']` a class/function?

Comment: There is nothing in the OLD CODE that is not compatible with PHP7. The issue, you're facing must be more complicated.

Comment: Have you checked the error log, if not please do and then show us the error or errors

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description, unless "Fix the code" is an acceptable answer ;-) Please edit the question and explain the exact problem you are facing, quoting the exact error messages if any.

Answer (score 3):

The code you are trying to run accomplishes two completely different things.

The first line of code is assigning the value of `$this->$rule['key'][$rule]` into the `$this->output` variable.

The second line of code is assigning the function result of `$this->$rule['key']($rule)` into the `$this->output` variable.

[This issue may be linked to the PHP 7 change there has been related variable handling.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling)

A small summary:

> PHP 7 now uses an abstract syntax tree when parsing source files. This has permitted many improvements to the language which were previously impossible due to limitations in the parser used in earlier versions of PHP, but has resulted in the removal of a few special cases for consistency reasons, which has resulted in backward compatibility breaks.